# Comment button invisible or missing. How to fix?

Tags: support, comments

The only options on a question and answer for me are share|edit and Answer (text field). Who are the lucky ones that can comment, how does that work, is there a link or button with 'comment'? what happens when you click it?
Am i the only one who does not see a 'add comment' ANY where on stackoverflow?

The only info i could find was "Comments are small addendums to each question or answer, intentionally limited in size and formatting. Comments are second-class citizens."

To formulate the question: how can i get access to comment functionality?

Answer (score 5):

> how can i get access to comment functionality?

Get 50 reputation on the site.

See the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) privilege.

Comment: Sharp, to the point, perfect answer. Thanks!